# How to use git submodule with a maven submodule?

Tags: java, git, maven

Id like to share a common service between projects using git submodules. The project structure is similar to this:

```
contacts project
  ├  security module (shared, uses common security DB)
  ├  contacts dao module
  ├  contacts web module 
  └  contacts api module

products project
  ├  security module (shared, uses common security DB)
  ├  products dao module
  ├  products web module
  └  products api module

accounts project
  ├  security module (shared, uses common security DB)
  ├  accounts dao module
  ├  accounts web module
  └  accounts api module
```

Generally, this is a micro service architecture, each project is entirely self contained and has its on git repo. The one part that is not is the shared security DB (not my choice). I'd like to develop the shared security service once and share it with all of the microservice projects using a git submodule (versioned mapping of a separate repo as a sub folder).

The git submodule would contain a maven submodule that can be included in each multi module maven project.

My problem is the parent reference in the maven submodules pom.

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.org.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-a-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
  </parent>
```

Because the maven pom contains an explicit reference to its parent I don't see any way to accomplish what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to make a Maven submodule a git submodule as well. Maven does all dependency handling for you. If you want to inspect the dependency source code then why not just clone the third-party lib instead? That keeps your workspace much cleaner. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you elaborate more in detail what exactly your problem is? To be honest I simply don't understand your problem?

Comment: updated the post with more information, hope this explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not to use maven submodules. Just create the shared service as a stand alone maven project in another git repo. Add the project as a git submodule to the target project and reference it from the parent pom and other submodules as needed.

This will set up the correct build dependencies but the shared project wont inherit anything from the parent pom.

Comment: Do you mind explain this visually?